# drush sup Gives "needs a higher bootstrap level" from within document root

Tags: drush, upgrading

I'm trying to upgrade a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7.  I do:

```
cd /path/to/sites/drupal6-site
drush sup
```

However I get the errors:

> Command site-upgrade needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   Command site-upgrade needs the following modules installed/enabled to run: update.

The settings file is at `./sites/default/settings.php`.

Running `drush dl update` (a module I'm apparently missing) also reports:

> No release history was found for the requested project (update).

What do I have to do to get `drush` to bootstrap?

Comment: Is the update status module enabled?

Comment: @jsheffers I don't know; how can I check?

Comment: `drush en update`...it'll either enable it, or tell you it's already enabled (it's a core module BTW). Can the user you're running drush as read the settings.php file? If you're running drush under the doc root, and you have a valid settings.php file, it's likely permissions are slightly off

Comment: If that drush command doesn't work you can always go to the modules admin page and search for update. Make sure it's enabled.